# To Get the Access Token for facebook api

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

To get the Access Token,

```
GET: https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
        client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
       &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
       &redirect_uri=uri
```

I tried with below GET method in **Graph API Explorer**

```
/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://XYZ.com/
```

But here I am getting error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Missing authorization code",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 1
  }
}
```

Can you please suggest, What should be pass in of **Code** Parameter.

```
/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXXXX&client_secret=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=http://XYZ.com/&code=??
```

Answer (score 4):

Your GET parameters are incorrect. Instead use this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=XXXXX&client_secret=XXXX&grant_type=client_credentials
```

Your'e missing the

> grant_type=client_credentials

parameter/value combination, which is required in order to receive access token.

Comment: By using yours above url, i got response like.
access_token=<App ID>|SJgcG4272bQmKz2Lbx_K5HRaQYU 

But while using this access_token in below url, 
https://graph.facebook.com/search?limit=25&offset=50&type=user&q=srihari&access_token=1416550685225787|SJgcG4272bQmKz2Lbx_K5HRaQYU

Now, i am getting error like:
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem as you

Answer (score 0):

This returns an app level oauth token but you did not yet introduce the '[scope](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.0)' parameter which authorizes a list of permissions:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=<client-id>&client_secret=<client-secret>&redirect_uri=http://example.com/&scope=<comma-separated-list-of-permissions>&grant_type=client_credentials
```

For list of the available permissions you can find them when you select "Get Access Token" from your App's Facebook Explorer dashboard -

```
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/<client-id>/
```