# Node.js - Get my account details from facebook graph api

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to get my facebook account details in node.js via facebook graph api (`graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=token`), but I can't get it to work with:

`access_token` = `appid` + `'|'` + `appsecret`

Here is my code:

```
var https=require('https');

var access_token = process.argv.slice(2)[0] + '|' + process.argv.slice(2)[1];
var options = {
    host: 'graph.facebook.com',
    path: '/me?access_token=' + access_token
};

https.get(options,function(res){
    var data = '';

    res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        data += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

And the error I'm getting:

> {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query
>   information about the current
>   user.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit:

After reading document again: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens.

I realize facebook has 4 types of token:

- User Access Token
- App Access Token = **app_id|app_secret**
- Page Access Token
- Client Token

App Access Token is used to read the app settings (not the user info).

And "https://graph.facebook.com/me" is for user info so we need to use User Access Token

---

example of using app access token:

https://graph.facebook.com/APP_ID/roles?&access_token=APP_ID|APP_SECRET

Comment: I know the `|` operator in `js` but is this token permanent if used like this? it's not working, anyway giving me this error:  `{"error":{"message":"Invalid OAuth access token.","type":"OAuthException","code":190}}`

Comment: give me the link to document, and how you you pass params to node?

Comment: [stackoverflow - trying to get app access token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948809/trying-to-get-app-access-token)

Comment: The document says: "graph.facebook.com/endpoint?key=value&access_token=app_id|app_secret", they tell us provide 1 of the two params, not both

Comment: It's the concatenation of the two strings!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43183/discussion-between-h4k1m-and-damphat)

Comment: please share code of how to access `user access_token`

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the `&grant_type=client_credentials` in the url:
[To Get the app Access Token for facebook api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960705/to-get-the-access-token-for-facebook-api).

But the app token isn't the one with which you get information about your user, in this case I need the `user access token` which I can get from [Graph Api Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)